# Can't install rhel-ia64 for itanium on hp rx2660 server

Tags: itanium

I have to install a rhel 4.8 ia64 on hp rx2660 server which ends every time to the same result
i thought maybe the dvd media corrupted then replaced it but no progress
i thought it maybe the os version so i tried rhel 5.8 ia64 also no progress
i used an external dvd wr but no thing also
The the following 3 pictures are the only result that i got every time
[this what appears after pressing ctrl + Alt + F4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdfN0.jpg)

[this what appears after pressing ctrl + Alt + F3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze8mC.jpg)

[this is what appears on the normal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Tzv.jpg)

Comment: Are you simply trying to boot from the CD or are you following the RHEL instructions? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/installation_guide/ch-ia64-intro

Comment: I'm just trying to boot from the CD